# For loop checking if not in list not working?

Tags: python

I have:

```
a=['a','v','c']  
b = ['d','a','c', 'e', 'b']
```

What I wanted to do was

```
for x in b:
    if x in a:
        b.remove(x)
```

But when I run this I get

```
b=['a','c','b']
```

I saw elsewhere a few ways you could modify it but none of them seem to be working.  For some reason when I add a print statement right below the "for" line.  It only prints out 'd', 'c', 'e'.  Why are the other two elements not being reached?

I was able to solve this by doing

b = [x for x in b if x in a]

but why wasn't it working in the first place?

Comment: Don't change the lengths of lists while iterating over them, it often leads to unexpected results.

Comment: It's bad practice to loop AND remove from the same list.

Comment: `list(set(b) - set(a))`…

Comment: Both Python2 and Python3 set `b` to `['d', 'c', 'e', 'b']` in your example. Can you kindly provide exact tested values when formulating a problem?